# Issues with the LibreOffice While Paste. Please FIx

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using **LibreOffice** from quite a time now. Till now, it was working like a pro. I was using **LibreOffice Writer** and doing some copy and paste. But suddenly I noticed that no matter what I copy, while paste, it paste only one particular **link**(copying some website links).

I have checked with **LibreOffice Calc**, the problem remains the same. But as soon as I paste it in **Notepad** it paste the right link.

So the issue is with the **LibreOffice** here. If any of know any solution of this then please help me. I need to use the LibreOffice, because all of the documents saved in LibreOffice document.

Thank you.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Does the problem persist after closing LO (including QuickStart, if running) and restarting, or after rebooting the PC? How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Pro. No, after rebooting, everything backs to normal. I am not sure how to reproduce the issue as this only happened once before.  Thank for helping me out here. I really appreciate.

Comment: OK - so please close the question, as the issue doesn't persist, and it's very unlikely that there will be useful answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it went away after a restart.